# Eclipse BIRT; Is there a way to adjust width of a Label or Text?

Tags: birt

I am new to BiRT. I need to design a report in BIRT that will contain a page of written text with 7 fields that are provided as inputs. I am trying to find a way to create the fields in a way similar to how we would do in Crystal Reports, by just creating each Label with the width we need. But the width adjustment seems to be missing from Properties. Please let me know how I could achieve this, appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Labels have no width in BIRT. BIRT uses a layout model which is quite different from Crystal Reports. The BIRT layout model is HTML/CSS-like. By default, all layout elements in BIRT have display: block - they use up all the available horizontal space.

If you want to show table headers aligned with the table data, then use a Table item in BIRT. If you want a form-like display (for e single record), then use a Grid Item. Place your labels and data inside the cells of the Grid/Table.